# Is there a way to represent a JSON field in EasyAdmin 3?

Tags: php, json, symfony, symfony5, easyadmin

I'm new to Symfony and still learning. I'm working currently on a Symfony application where I have a table that represents projects and every project have `id`, `title`, `startDate`, `endDate` and `fields` where `fields` is a JSON field that contains data representing differents columns that are custom to the project and can be added, updated or deleted by a user.

The data inside that field is like this:

```
{
  "columns": {
    "column1": "string",
    "column2": "integer"
  },
  "rows": [
    {
      "column1": "foo",
      "column2": 22
    },
    {
      "column1": "bar",
      "column2": 23
    }
  ]
}
```

`"columns"` represents custom columns added to a specific project and `"rows"` represents the data in every column. `"string"` and `"integer"` represent data type in every column.

#### My Question:

I can extract the columns and values using [DoctrineJsonFunctions](https://github.com/ScientaNL/DoctrineJsonFunctions) and I'm using EasyAdmin 3, but my question is how can I read the project columns when viewing project details knowing that every project may have different columns? Or is there any better solution than using JSON field? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/issues/4388#issuecomment-1132194888) comment from @myfluxi:

Create a new class for Json form type:

```
namespace App\Form;

use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Form\Type\CodeEditorType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\CallbackTransformer;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class JsonCodeEditorType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder
            ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
                static fn ($object) => json_encode($object, \JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR | \JSON_PRETTY_PRINT),
                static fn ($json) => json_decode($json, true, 512, \JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR)
            ));
    }

    public function getParent(): string
    {
        return CodeEditorType::class;
    }
}
```

In the configureFields method of your CRUD Controller:

```
yield CodeEditorField::new('result')
    ->setFormType(JsonCodeEditorType::class)
```

Answer (score 0):

In easyadmin 3, you can use the ArrayField to display JSON data.

Comment: ArrayField is not associative and cannot handle nesting.

Comment: Mapping between doctrine type and existing field types can be found at https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/fields.html#mapping-between-doctrine-types-and-easyadmin-fields