# Array to string conversion in EasyAdmin 3 (Symfony 5)

Tags: json, symfony, symfony5, easyadmin, easyadmin3

I'm trying to display a json array on the EasyAdmin detail page. I read here [Is there a way to represent a JSON field in EasyAdmin 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63999004/is-there-a-way-to-represent-a-json-field-in-easyadmin-3) that you can use ArrayField in EasyAdmin 3 to display a json array, which would make sense to me as that is the only field in EasyAdmin that could display it so I added it like this:

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
    return [
        ArrayField::new('status', $this->translator->trans('form.label.status'))->onlyOnDetail(),
    ];
}
```

But it gives me this error:
`An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion").` Do I need to add something else to it or does it not work at all?

Comment: Do you use the ArrayField from 'EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\ArrayField;' ?

Comment: @alessandro_podo yes I do

Comment: can you try ArrayField::new('status'); if that works?

Comment: @madebyjo_l, you specified at the end `...->onlyOnDetail()` so if you're not on the detail page you should still get the error. I hope I'm wrong by assuming you're not on the detail page that's why the error is still showing. Let me know by trying just `ArrayField::new('status');`

Comment: Not only the ArrayField can process arrays: the ChoiceField can do it too. To this: "Do I need to add something else to it or does it not work at all?", the answer is yes. That should work for sure. You have done a mistake somewhere.
You can either check your 'translator' function, your Entity's getter and setter for this propery, try to add the toString() method to your entity, try to use the "yield" syntax instead of returning an array,...

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround that resolved the issue in my situation where I wanted just to show JSON on details page

So in your entity add a get function as an unmapped field as indicated in the official documentaiton
https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/fields.html#unmapped-fields

for example

```
public function getJsonField() {
  return json_encode($this->yourEntityJsonAttribute);
}
```

then in configureFields function in your CrudController add your field like this

```
TextAreaField::new('jsonField')->onlyOnDetail()
```

You can also read the json attribute and generate an HTML string in the getJsonField function then in configure field just add renderAsHtml in th field like this

```
TextAreaField::new('jsonField')->onlyOnDetail()->renderAsHtml()
```

Wish this suits your case too, Good luck

Answer (score 0):

change "status" to a multiplicity  "statuses"
Worked for me with changing "print" to "prints"

Answer (score 0):

What I do to render my json fields is

```php
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\CodeEditorField;
use App\Controller\Admin\Form\Type\Field\JsonCodeEditorType;

// ...

class MyCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{

//...
    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [

            CodeEditorField::new('status')
                ->setLanguage('javascript')
                ->setFormType(JsonCodeEditorType::class)
                ->formatValue(function ($value, $entity) {
                    return json_encode($value, \JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR | \JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
                })
                ->setFormTypeOption('attr', ['style' => 'min-height: 30px'])
        ]
    }
}
```

with

```php
<?php

namespace Arpha\DigistekkerBundle\Controller\Admin\Form\Type\Field;

use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Form\Type\CodeEditorType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\CallbackTransformer;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;


class JsonCodeEditorType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
        $builder
            ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
                static fn($object) => json_encode($object, \JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR | \JSON_PRETTY_PRINT),
                static fn($json) => json_decode($json, true, 512, \JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR)
            ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return CodeEditorType::class;
    }
}
```